# The Heat Added in a Reversible Polytropic Process

Tags: mechanical-engineering, heat-transfer

*The question*: Consider $1\ kg$ of air at $32\ C$ that is expanded by a reversible polytropic process with $n=1.25$ until the pressure is halved. Determine the heat transfer.
Specific heat constant volume for air is $0.1786\  kJ/kg.K$

The correct answer is: $17.02\  kJ$ heat added

---

My work so far:

$$\frac{T_{1}}{T_{2}} = \frac{P_{1}}{P_{2}}^{\frac{n-1}{n}}$$
    $$n = 1.25$$
    $$\frac{P_{1}}{P_{2}} = 0.5$$
    $$T_{1} = 32+273$$

You'd get $T_2 = 350.352$

$$ Q = m*Cv*(T_2-T_1)$$

I get $8.00\ kJ$ something.

**What am I doing wrong?**

Comment: In your energy conservation, you have not included the $p dV$ work that occurred during the expansion.

Comment: And here is the proof for the specific heat of polytropic expansion $C_{n}$ found in Mark's answer : http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/108933/formula-for-molar-specific-heat-capacity-in-polytropic-process

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use the specific heat constant of constant volume - a polytropic process isn't constant volume or constant pressure.

Instead, what is derived is the specific heat of polytopic expansion:

$$c_n = c_v\frac{n-k}{n-1}$$

Where k is the [heat capacity ratio](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heat_capacity_ratio).  Air is considered a diatomic ideal gas, so k = 1.4.  When I lookup air's specific heat for volume via [engineering toolbox](http://www.engineeringtoolbox.com/specific-heat-capacity-gases-d_159.html) is $c_v = 0.718 kJ/kg*K$, so I'm using that.

So, here's how I would approach it (note you did have p2/p1 backwards as well):

$$ T_2 = T_1(\frac{p_2}{p_1})^{1-1/n} = 305K*(0.5)^{0.2} = 265.52K $$

$$ c_n = 0.718\frac{-0.15}{.25} = -0.4308 \frac{kJ}{kg*K} $$

$$ Q = m c_n (T_2 - T_1) = 1kg * (-0.4308)*(265.5K - 305K) = 17.02 kJ $$.

Source for equations - the ever useful [MERM](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1591264146).  Don't take the PE exam without it.